# How do i edit a system file when i am root user but i receive “you are not in the sudoers file. ”

Tags: ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 12.04(LTS) 64 bit. i have edited "group" file in directory /etc. i added my user name which is "erfan" in front of "vboxusers" as following :

in below you can see some lines of my group file

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
.
.
.
erfan:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:
debian-xfs:x:125:
vboxusers:x:126:erfan
vboxsf:x:127:
guest-59wkHG:x:128:
```

after this change i can not use "sudo" command and i receive following message:

"erfan is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

i can not install any package and manage my operating system.

i think if i can find a way to delet my user name ("erfan") in front of "vboxusers", then this problem will resolve.

could you give me an idea to delet it and edit "group" file? or any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: You've answered your own question... to be able to do admin tasks that require "sudo" capability you need to be in the sudoers file... this has nothing to do with the groups file...

Comment: You shouldn't manually edit this file. Restore it from a backup.

Comment: If you want to undo the change, just boot from install or rescue media, mount your root file system, and undo the change from there. Or easier, restore it from a known good backup.

Answer (score 1):

Default sudo configuration (`/etc/sudoers`) says - members of groups *admin* and *sudo* can execute `sudo` command (and there is no *admin* group in Ubuntu, so *sudo* group only).

Apparently after your edit, your user is no longer a member of this group.

To fix it you can:

- boot from Live CD
- open terminal
- `sudo su -` will switch you to root
- mount your root partition (ie `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` - where sda1 is your root partition)
- edit group file (`joe /mnt/etc/group`) and add your user back to *sudo* group
- unmount root partition (`umount /mnt`)
- reboot
- give someone a hug :)